# Javascript In URL Bar

Tags: javascript

When I type in something like

```
javascript:alert("test");
```

into the url bar, it works fine. But when I type something like

```
javascript:window.onclick=function(){alert('hi');}
```

It brings me to a page saying

```
function (){alert('hi');}
```

BTW, I am running Firefox 33. Yes, the code works if I type it into the console.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it in an *immediately-invoked function expression*:

```
javascript:(function (){ window.onclick = function () { alert( "Hi" ); } }());
```

Comment: Does not explain the issue the OP is facing, yes it solves it.

Comment: The issue is with the resulting value of the expression. Using an IIFE makes the overall expression evaluate to `undefined`, which is the key to making things work. An IIFE is not the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can just make sure that your `javascript:` URL ends up with an `undefined` value:

```
javascript:window.onclick=function(){alert('hi');},undefined
```

The semantics of a `javascript:` URL are that the result of evaluating whatever's after the `:` is taken to be the URL to load, unless the result is `undefined`.  The IIFE in Mr. Sampson's answer accomplishes that, but so does anything that leaves the result of expression evaluation `undefined`, as the comma-operator example above does.

It's a good idea to make sure that your `javascript:` URL (or bookmarklet, which is kind-of what we're talking about) is URL-encoded, though browsers are usually pretty tolerant in the URL bar. If you want to save the URL as a bookmark, I've always encoded it.